# Where to add first breakpoint when UI5 starts?

Tags: sapui5

I am new to SAPUI5 (or) OpenUI5, I am trying to understand the core framework libraries which would form the basis for further understanding, while going through few blogs I learnt that  we have  a class "createClass" which helps to create any class, there are also few aspects such as "oClassInfo"  & "FNMetaImpl".

I would request your help in understanding this aspect.

Also I would like to understand where the whole UI5 starts, could you tell me where should I keep my first break point to understand where it all starts?

Answer (score 1):

1.first make yourself familiarized with UI5(high level).i mean how to use(create a button, a page), not the deep insight

2.understand how class, module works in js

without those, you will be wasting your time